# How can I compare a master list of serial numbers and compare it to a seperate list and have it mark duplicates?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sheets("Die Sizes").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:= _
    "=cells(i,ForgeSchedule!B2)", TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

This is what I have so far. This will compare the specific cells in the secondary list to the master list. This means I would have to rerun this one at a time changing the "B2" to B3 all the way to B3200. How can I get it to do that automatically? I'm very new to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need a loop. Perhaps something like this (air code):

```
Dim lngRow As Long

Sheets("Die Sizes").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
For lngRow = 2 To 3200
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:= _
        "=cells(i,ForgeSchedule!B" & lngRow & ")", TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Next lngRow
```